# Which Android Camera API should I use

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-camerax

I have a requirement to implement an in application camera behavior where a user can take a picture of a QR Code and then I will use Google Play services API to process and decode the QR Code.

So all I need to do is take a picture.

Furthermore, I know the exact device models that this app is being deployed to. Currently it is two devices, eventually, it might be three device models (all API 21+).

From what I have read, the Jetpack CameraX API is developed to simplify device specific code.

If my goal is to just implement the most straightforward code for this requirement... should I look at using the Camera API, or Camera2 API, or CameraX API?

Comment: You do not need Play Services to decode a QR code. [There are offline options](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/81?sort=created), some of which integrate the camera logic for you. Beyond that, of your three options, try CameraX, or try existing camera libraries like Fotoapparat or CameraKit-Android.

Comment: Usually, it's not enough to "simply take a picture" to take good care of QR codes. The QR libraries prefer to feed the live stream from camera to the decoder, so that the user doesn't need to click the "capture" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `CameraX` is just a wrapper about the `Camera2` API. Read [following article](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax)

In your case which is quite simplistic, taking a photo can be done by many libraries such as

> QR Code Reader

But if you still want to develop taking picture functionality and your devices are 21+, I would suggest you go for `CameraX`, since it will be updated very frequently and you wont have to worry about different behavior in different devices as explained in this [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYkTXJ2TuiA&feature=youtu.be)