# How to measure radiation(Non Ionizing) [Android SDK] for a Radiation measuring application

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

I need a way to measure the non-ionizing radiation around me through the smart phones. I have found several applications on the google Play Store which have an RF meter functionality which measures the Radio Frequency. Through my application, I am only able to measure the Electromagnetic fields using the inbuilt sensors. However, I need to measure the radiations of type Radio Frequency.

```
public class NonIonizingRadiationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_non_ionizing_radiation);
        manager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        float azimuth = Math.round(sensorEvent.values[0]);
        float pitch = Math.round(sensorEvent.values[0]);
        float roll = Math.round(sensorEvent.values[0]);

        double tesla = Math.sqrt((azimuth*azimuth) + (pitch*pitch) + (roll*roll));

        
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(sensor!=null){
            manager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error, Sensor not available/supported.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        manager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Reference links (from playstore): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tm.radiation.meetr&hl=en-IN ; https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dainaapp.emfdetector.emfmeter.ultimateemffinder

Comment: A typical magnetometer's bandwidth is way too low. For example, the magnetometer on my phone mentions a response [up to 1 kHz](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/495/MMC5633NJL_RevA_3-12-20.pdf). Are you targeting some kind of specialty phone with a dedicated RF power meter chip? And have you verified that those apps actually measure a wide variety of radiation, rather than just "cheating" and only reporting the power from the subset of frequencies and protocols that the modem reports?

Comment: My goal is to measure the non ionizing radiations around me through my smart phone. I dont have special equipments to verify these apps other than the reviews it has.

Comment: For non-ionizing radiation, you only really have two sensors - the camera (for 400 THz-800THz), and the modem (for whatever cell frequencies it can receive + WiFi + one or two GPS bands). That represents a very narrow subset of non-ionizing radiation, and each sensor is going to require different code to infer the effective energy from its readings. Is this actually enough coverage for your needs?

Comment: Yes it is enough for my needs atleast

Comment: but how do I capture those non ionizing radiations through the camera or the modem sensor? I couldnt find anything related on the internet nor I have much experience with sensors.

Comment: Each of these devices has its own respective API, and it's too broad for a single Stack Overflow question - e.g. going from camera brightness to luminous flux to energy requires a number of considerations. Some are on-topic here, like [how to capture an image with the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56501853/which-android-camera-api-should-i-use). Others are more physics/engineering and are off-topic for this site, and you may need to do some calibration. For the RF ones, you also have APIs like...

Comment: ... [SignalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength). My recommendation would be to identify a specific API/device for each question, so you have more focused questions. A single post covering everything from visible light through the camera API to CDMA + WiFi + GPS is too broad.